# Vuetify data-table body.append slot mobile breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datatable, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have this code in a vue component that uses Vuetify data table.

```
<template slot="body.append">
    <tr>
       <th :colspan="6" class="text-right">Total:</th>               
    </tr>
</template>
```

The problem is that on mobile my custom `tr` row is not getting the CSS classes similar to the default data table

```
<tr class="v-data-table__mobile-table-row">
  <td class="v-data-table__mobile-table-row"></td>
</tr>
```

How could I add those classes dynamically like the default data tables does. And also is there any way I can disable `:colspan="6"` on mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take advantage of [`breakpoints`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service) and add class binding if the breakpoint name equals to `xs` (mobile size), so add a computed called mobile that detects the breakpoint :

```
<template slot="body.append">
    <tr :class="{'v-data-table__mobile-table-row':isMobile}">
       <th :colspan="`${isMobile?6:1}`" :class="{'v-data-table__mobile-row':isMobile}" class="text-right">Total:</th>               
    </tr>
</template>

....

computed:{
  isMobile(){
    return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name==='xs'
   }
}
```